# Does Windows 11 take advantage of efficient cores?

Tags: cpu, windows-11, cpu-cores, intel

Ever since Intel introduced "efficient cores" I've been wondering if Windows 11 does take advantage of that in terms of lower power consumption or does it simply let the CPU handles it automatically?

Answer (score 2):

The new Intel CPU architecture was one of the reasons that Windows 11 was
conceived.

So the answer is positive.

See for example the article
[How to enable Efficiency Mode for apps in Windows 11](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/efficiency-mode-apps-windows-11/).